# Json file -extract a spesific key value

Tags: json, dictionary, key, key-value

[image]

Hi. Can someone please help me on how to get the value for the key "lonn" from this json string :). I have attempted to print out the value of the key "lonn" which is 700 000, but the print function returns an error. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: The property you are trying to access is nested inside other objects. Try accessing the dictionary index like this `data["bedrift"]["ansatt"]["utbetalt"]["lonn"]`

Comment: Hi, the above mentioned solution works for the keys "bedrift", "ansatt" and "navn", but when I try to add "utbetalt" and "lonn" it returns the following: TypeError: string indices must be integers.